Многомерный массив как удалить
есть массив вида
$arr[1]['one']="1";
$arr[1]['twoo']="2";

unset($arr[1]['one']) удаляет ключ со значением а при передаче тех же данных через переменную

$del = $arr[1]['one'];
unset($del) ничего не происходит


Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Потому что так работает функция unset(). В случае с вызовом unset($arr[1]['one']), Вы напрямую удаляете элемент массива $arr. Когда Вы пишете $del = $arr[1]['one']; и затем делаете unset($del), Вы просто присваиваете значение ключа 'one' переменной $del, а потом удаляете только эту переменную. Это никак не повлияет на сам массив $arr. Переменная $del -- это копия значения, а не ссылка на элемент массива.

Писать как в первом варианте.... или писать $del = &$arr[1]; unset($del['one']);

если у вас появился новый вопрос, задайте его, пожалуйста, с помощью кнопки «задать вопрос» в правом верхнем углу страницы; если нужно указать контекст, дайте ссылку на этот вопрос.
